# Most efficient way to get total number of 'online users' from a Connections dynamodb table fed from a websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, websocket, web-applications, amazon-dynamodb

I have a `Dynamodb` table for `Connections`. The idea is that when a `user` logs into a website, a `connection` will be made via `websockets` and this `connection` information is stored in this `table`.

Now, we have a feature we want to release which shows **total users online**. My thoughts are, i could add a new `API` end point which scans `dynamodb` and returns the **count of connections**, but this would involve a `dynamodb` scan every time the UI refreshes - guessing this would be very expensive.

Another option i thought of was creating an `API` and an scheduled lambda that calls this `API` once every 10 minutes and uploads the count to an `S3 file`, the `API` for the UI could then be pointed at the `S3` file which would be cheaper but this would not be **real time** as its 10 mins out of date potentially.

Alternatively, i tried to use the `/@connections` end point to see if this returned the total connections via the `websocket API` but seems i am getting `CORS` error when doing so and there's no way in `AWS` for us to be able to set `CORS` on the provided HTTP `@connections` route.

I would be interested in some ideas how to achieve this in the most efficient way :) my estimated table of connections could have anywhere between 5k-10k items.

Comment: Have a dynamodb stream set up that triggers a lambda which updates a counter which is then easily query-able using whatever API you want.

Comment: Be aware of [Monitoring WebSocket API execution with CloudWatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-logging.html) if using API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing here would be to use an item in the table to hold the live item count.

Add connection:

`Add connection to DDB -> Stream -> Lambda -> Increment count item`

Remove connection:

`Remove connection from DDB -> Stream -> Lambda -> Decrement count item`

This will allow you to efficiently gain the number of live-users on the system by a simple `GetItem`.

You just need to be mindful that a single item can consume only 1000WCU per second, so if you are trying to update the item more than 1000 times per second you will either:

1. Have to aggregate the events in Lambda, using a sliding window.
2. Artificially shard the `count item` n ways, count-item0, count-item1 etc...